# Dumping Registers in PPC

Tags: assembly, xbox360, powerpc

I'm trying to dump the value of `r5` so that I can see what `var_A0` data is. I am trying to dump in PPC since I'm using UART debugging on the XBox 360 console,
EX): I'm trying to figure out what the value of `var_A0` is

```
addi      r5, r1, 0x110+var_A0
```

Code im using is ::

```
PrintKey:
    lis     %r29, -0x8000
    ori     %r29, %r29, 0x100
    sldi    %r3, %r29, 32
    ori     %r3, %r3, 0x247C  # 0x800001000000247C
    li      %r4, 0x80
    bl      printAddress
printAddress:
    mr      %r30, %r3
    mr      %r11, %r4           # text size
    mtctr   %r11
```

But this only print the physical code in the HV not the Registers Data

Comment: And your question is? What have you tried doing and what isn't working?

Comment: Please don't add (relevant) information such as code you tried in comments, edit it as part of your question

Comment: ok i apologize first time using the site

Comment: `var_A0` is a constant. It's value plus 0x110, is encoded as an immediate operand in the instruction `addi  r5, r1, 0x110+var_A0`. To find out what `var_A0` is you don't need to print out the value of anything,  You just need to find out what the value of the immediate operand encoded in the instruction actually is and subtract 0x110.  You can probably do that by changing how your disassembler displays the immediate operand. Either that or you can disassemble the instruction manually.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you'll need to sort out here:

The `printAddress` function looks like it takes an address in `r3`, and a size in `r4`, then (presumably) prints the contents of memory at that address. We have no way of telling how that printing is done, as the code to do that is missing from your question.

Consequently, you probably don't want to use `printAddress` to display the value of `r5`. You could probably adapt the actual printing code (which is missing) to just print the contents of a register, rather than memory.

However: the actual thing you want to find out (the value of `var_A0`) is likely to be determined at compile time (or at least during final link - is this binary statically linked?). Check the disassembled code, and/or check for dynamic relocation entries if this is a dynamic executable.

Alternatively, you could use `printAddress` to print the contents of the memory containing the `addi` instruction, then manually decode the instruction to determine the immediate value used in the `addi`.